# Select from psql and mysql with one query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

i have strange issue,

i need select from psql and mysql in one query.

I have users in mysql, and for example location in mysql
also need get by userId for example orders from psql.

I need all raw datas in one file.

Of course, Excel can concatenate from two files. But that's not cool.

> Sample Three table

Users in **mysql**.

Id, FirstName, LastName, email, LocationId

Location in **mysql**

Id, City, Address, Zip

And Orders in **Psql**.

Id, UserId, ItemName, Quantity, Price

I need something like that:

```
Select u.FirstName, u.LastName, o.Quantity, 
loc.City from Mysql.Users u
join Mysql.Locations loc on loc.Id = u.Id
join Psql.Orders o on o.UserId = u.Id
```

Comment: Can you please share your codes / data samples so we can understand the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreign tables with https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw and then join them in posstgres

Like it says on the guithub page

> MySQL Foreign Data Wrapper for PostgreSQL
>
> This PostgreSQL extension implements a Foreign Data Wrapper (FDW) for
> MySQL.
>
> Please note that this version of mysql_fdw works with PostgreSQL and
> EDB Postgres Advanced Server 9.6, 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14.